# Why do i have to press ctrl+d several times for scanf to see it?

Tags: c, scanf, eof

in my program i need to read numbers in this format - number, number, number etc., and it ends when user press ctrl+d. I switch `scanf("%d",&i)` and `scanf("%c",&c)`.

My problem is, that the program ends, when i press ctrl+d 3 times, the first and second time it ignores it for some reason. I also noticed, that if i debug and write : " 5, 6ctrl+d " it reads " 5, " and then it waits for next input. Why, when there is 6 and ctlr+d already ? Thanks

My code :

```
for (;;)
{
 if (cislo==1)
  {
   res=scanf("%d",&matice[x][y]);
   if (res==-1)
   {
    ...
    return 1;  /* i want EOF to be after number, not char */
   } else
   {
    ...
    cislo=0;
   }
  } else
  {  
   res=scanf("%c",&znak);
   if (res==-1)
   {
    ...
    break;
   } else
   {
   ...
   cislo=1;
   }; 
 };
};
```

Comment: Bump, any more help please ? No idea how to edit the code so it works

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to read 3 inputs with 3 `scanfs()`, each `CTRL-D` treated as one input, hence your program ignores initial two and terminates after 3rd.

For input like `5, 6ctrl+d`, the `scanf()` reads entire string, but only converts `5` to appropriate number and stores in provided variable. The string after that is discarded. Again next `scanf()` waits to read next number.

Comment: Editted my post, so there is code. I am not quite sure what are you saying that i should change