# EOF control D not working at first time

Tags: c, eof

i have the same issue like this

[Why do i have to press ctrl+d several times for scanf to see it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20285913/why-do-i-have-to-press-ctrld-several-times-for-scanf-to-see-it)

i want to quit the cycle, when i enter number 0 or ctrl + D. it work only if i hit the combination repeatly, in the topic i metioned, there was explained the reason, but i dont know how to fix my code, so i decided to ask

here is part of my code

```
do{
        scanf("%f", &coin);
        payment=payment+coin;
        if ((coin !=0) && (coin !=100) && (coin !=50) && (coin !=20) && (coin !=10) && (coin !=5) && (coin !=2) && (coin !=1) && (coin !=0.5) && (coin*100 !=20) && (coin*100 !=10) && (coin*100 !=5) && (coin*100 !=2) && (coin*100 !=1)){
            if (coin>=1){
                rest=coin;
                while(rest>=1)
                    rest--;
                if (rest!=0)
                    printf("%.2f is invalid!\n", coin); 
                else
                    printf("%.0f is invalid!\n", coin); 
            }               

            else
                printf("%.2f is invalid!\n", coin);

            return(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }


    }while (coin != 0 && (getchar()!=EOF));
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of checking just for `Ctrl-D`, check for success of `scanf`.

`scanf` will return `1` for successful read of `coin`, else `break` from `while`.

```
if (scanf("%f", &coin) != 1)
   break;
```

Also change condition for while

```
 }while (coin != 0 );
```

Comment: I tried that, and now i need to press ctrl + d two times instead of 4 or 5 times, depends on how many numbers i already had in line. As is said below, i need one ctrl + d to exit scanf, and the second is actually working. But i need the first time to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like you are something else wrong.  Can you post your complete new code..  With above logic if you enter 10 20 30 ctrl-d loop will run 3 times for valid entry and 4th time to exit from while..

Answer (score 1):

First ctrl D exits the scanf

Second one exits the getchar()

That's why!

Hope this helps

Comment: Right. But *only* for terminal input. On a tty you can happily continue reading (just to get another EOF in this case), on a "real file" EOF *is* end-of-file, try to read more and you'll get the same.